# React - Dos componentes dentro de otro

Tags: html, html5, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

Tengo esta aplicación en react donde defino dos componentes un header i un footer siguiente esta estructura

Con este código el header

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h2>Header</h2>
        );
    }
}
```

El  código del footer

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class Footer extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h2>Footer</h2>
        );
    }
}
```

Y lo que intento hacer es desde otro componente llamar a estos dos para renderizarlos, para ello hago esto

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Header from "./components/layout/header.js";
import Footer from "./components/layout/footer.js";

export default class ListItems extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }


    render() {
      return <Header/> contenido <Footer/>;
    }
  }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error que me da es este

```
./src/components/items/list-cars.component.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './components/layout/footer.js' in   
'C:\xampp\htdocs\react-login\src\components\items'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas `import Footer from "./components/layout/footer.js";` le estás indicando con `./` que la ruta es relativa a la ruta donde se encuentra el archivo actual. Como `list-cars.component.js` se encuentra ubicado dentro de la carpeta `items/`, deberías retroceder un nivel con `../`, algo como:

```
import Header from "../layout/header.js";
import Footer from "../layout/footer.js";
```

o remover el `./` para que considere el root de tu proyecto:

```
import Header from "components/layout/header.js";
import Footer from "components/layout/footer.js";
```

Otro punto, es que `.js` no es estrictamente necesario, así que también puedes removerlo si quieres.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Arreglado. 1000 gracias